I want to enter a character into any index of a 2D array that has been printed onto the terminal from the terminal
I am fairly new to programming, and after a bunch of tutorials I decided to build my own tictactoe game.
After making the board and printing it in a table form, what I am trying to do now is to be able to sequentially enter characters (x's and o's) into the board from the terminal in the positions the player may want to put them in, and have it print after each entry.
Here is what I have done. The function is the play() function. All programs are in C++. The solution I tried is not allowing me enter the character into the very spot (index) I want it to:
class Board{
public:
    const static int rows = 5;
    const static int cols = 5;
    char grid[rows][cols]{};

    Board(){
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                if (j == 1 || j == 3) {
                    grid[i][j] = vertical;
                }

                if (i == 1 || i == 3) {
                    grid[i][j] = horizontal;
                }
            }
        }
    }

        void printBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                cout << grid[i][j] << "\t";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    void play() { 
       printBoard();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                if (Board().grid[i][j] != vertical && Board().grid[i][j] != horizontal) {
                    cin >> grid[i][j];
                }
            }
            printBoard();
        }
    }
};

In the function play(), I tried implementing a for loop that will allow me to enter a character and It will print the board after that character has been implemented:
if (Board().grid[i][j] != vertical && Board().grid[i][j] != horizontal) { cin >> grid[i][j];

If I'm understanding you correctly then what you want is not supported by standard C++ I/O. Instead you should use a third party library, such as the ncurses library on Linux, or the Console API on Windows.

Standard C++ offers no way to position the cursor at an arbitrary place on the screen, or to read characters from an arbitrary place. That's why you need a third party library.

@john thank you. So If I am to not incorporate the library, I guess I will have to just have the user input which index they want to have their character in.

Seems reasonable. Since you are fairly new it's best to stick to standard C++ for now. There's plenty to be learning as it is without adding third party libraries into the mix.

@Pelz04, my post is primarily focused on MS operating system, even if, as specified, it can be adapted for Unix-like operating systems. However, I would like to know the OS where you are working on or, if your goal is not to make it cross-platform, to know the different OS, so I can eventually update the answer to include all of them.

@LoS I'm using MS OS as well. Making it cross-platform isn't my goal for now, as this is a beginner project and I am fairly new to building, but don't let that stop you from updating the answer to make it cross-platform.

Maybe you can store the position of the cursor, and "draw" it in your printBoard() function. You may need another thread to update the position of the cursor.
Something like:
class Board{
public:
    const static int rows = 5;
    const static int cols = 5;
    char grid[rows][cols]{};

    Board(){
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                if (j == 1 || j == 3) {
                    grid[i][j] = vertical;
                }

                if (i == 1 || i == 3) {
                    grid[i][j] = horizontal;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void printBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                cout << grid[i][j] << "\t";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        // TODO draw the cursor here
    }

    void play() { 
       // TODO start a thread for Update()
       while(true) {
           printBoard();
       }
    }

    void Update() {
        while(true) {
            // TODO get a key from keyboard
            // TODO if the key is ↑↓←→: update cursorX and cursorY
            // TODO if the key is alpha, update the grid
        }
    }
private:
    int cursorX{0};
    int cursorY{0};
};


To create a more interactive CLI, it is possible to use arrow keys to select the position where the symbol can be inserted. Beginning from a defaulted position, which may be the top-leftmost cell or the first free cell in the grid, it is possible to press one of the four arrow keys to move the target position a cell at a time and confirm it by pressing the enter key.
In this case, the grid array does not represent both data and presentation, but just the data. This means that the 3x3 matrix contains only the two symbols (nought, cross) and empty positions. The building of the external structure, which represents the skeleton of the tic-tac-toe table, is performed separately during the print operation. Furthermore, the implementation is valid only on Microsoft operating systems due to the used function to capture keys, getch(). To extend the implementation to work on Unix-like operating systems, it is possible to change a little the code by using the corresponding counterpart of the getch() function.
The input() member function is implemented in order that the defaulted position be the first cell in the grid, regardless it be already occupied. To represent the coordinates, the two variables i, j are used. The main part of the function body consists of a switch, which checks whether an arrow key has been pressed and then updates the coordinates accordingly, and a loop, which continues the process of capturing the key, checking it and printing the preview of the grid until the enter key is pressed. As the loop interrupts, it is assumed that the position identified by the two coordinates be the target cell, and therefore the specific token t is inserted. It is important to note that, if the arrow key tries to push the current position out of the grid, the input is ignored.
The print_preview_board() member function takes the two coordinates i, j as inputs and prints the grid with the highlighted cell. In this way, it is possible to know which is the selected position, verifying the effect of every movement.
Example:
void input(char t)
{
  char c;
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  while((c = getch()) != '\r'){
    switch(c){
      case KEY_UP:
        if(i != 0)
          --i;
      break;
      case KEY_DOWN:
        if(i != 2)
          ++i;
      break;
      case KEY_LEFT:
        if(j != 0)
          --j;
      break;
      case KEY_RIGHT:
        if(j != 2)
          ++j;
      break;
    }
    this->print_preview_board(i, j);
  }
  this->grid[i][j] = t;
}

